# I can't match the colour in Blender with real pictures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, photorealism

I am making product renders in blender. This means I need to accurately make a colour in blender cycles. But if I make an iPhone for example, I can't get the Colour in blender to match the colour of the official pictures. I've tried to use the official hex codes, but the colour's still turning out wrong.
Hope anyone can help me out

Comment: I'm no expert, but check that you have Color Management > View Transform set to Filmic in the Render Properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few layers to this.

Using HEX codes is a problem. It's a very flawed way to communicate color if the actual color space is not specified(and unfortunately it isn't usually). Apple uses P3 color space for example that is different than sRGB, so the same HEX code will be 2 different colors in those spaces. If you get a plain HEX code, it is probably most often in sRGB, but not always as it may also be in AdobeRGB or P3 or occasionally even in any other color space out of infinitely many. So it's always a guess. You should know what color space the HEX codes are in. If you start wondering - yes, indeed, almost everybody is doing it wrong. And yes, even professionals working in relevant areas.

Filmic might be part of the "problem". As whatever you input goes through the color transform after it's rendered. You could use "Standard" sRGB color transform(set it in the Render tab, Color management panel of the Properties editor). If you input a HEX code into any color input in Blender it is assumed to be sRGB color space so if it is indeed in sRGB the color should be interpreted correctly and internally converted to Blender's linear reference color space and back to sRGB at the end when it's rendered. Of course you will be using screen referred workflow from that point and should adjust the lights and shaders in your scene not to be too bright, since standard sRGB transform will just clip values higher than 1 in your render. This is not so called "PBR" workflow in that case and you should keep that in mind.

But wait, there is more. The other issue is that when you input some color into some property of some shader, that shader usually also has other parts in it like most will have diffuse and glossy components at least. So the end color in the render does change(as it should). It also depends on the scene and lighting it receives from various light sources and secondary bounces from other objects in the scene. So if you have realistic shaders and lighting, the hues, saturation and tones will change. This is unavoidable no matter what you do.

If you wanted to retain high dynamic range of your realistic scene in scene referred workflow and use color transforms like Filmic or AgX, one way to work with it could be to compare your render result to your desired result and adjust as needed visually. This would ensure the result matches your perception of the goal. You could judge that without relying on any numerical values of any input just by trusting your own perception. Since in this way you judge the rendered result directly as opposed to only some inputs, you also take into account everything that happens in your scene, so that is easier, but since you are matching the output to some specific desired result, it will loose realism(what is that anyway?.. - it's all probably based on your guesses anyway) of how a particular color would actually look in the specific scene and lighting conditions. It makes sense to have exact same lighting conditions in your scene as in your reference to make things easier. Of course chances are in real world situations you might not be able to have photographs taken in precise lighting conditions and high enough dynamic range and then developed in Blender using the same color transform, so this might involve a lot of guesses and artistic choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've heard blender 4.0 will have AGX as a standard option, so I hope that'll help me. Most of the times I want to replicate a color, I will just eyeball it, which might actually be the best. It doesn't give me perfect results, but honestly I don't think anyone will notice. But again, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: AgX will not help you match color. It might help you match the perception of a color on an object. It's not about matching colors, it's about showing real scene on narrower dynamic range device. If you concentrate on a single color, you will have a lot harder time with AgX. But it's never a single color if you have shading and realistic scene. Matching the whole look of an object might be a better approach. There is no color picker or hex code for that, but luckily it's all about human perception and each of us have that.